# What is the convention when relevant data needs to be stored in a join table?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design, associations

Suppose you have a data model that is something like

```
class Question

has_and_belongs_to_many :choices

end
```

Now suppose, on that choices model, there is a position column. What is the best way to access that information without having horrible messy queries / models?

The beauty of has_and_belongs_to_many is that it keeps things concise and simple. Is there a way to accomplish that, but still have access to my `questions_choices`.position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You should use `has_many :through` if you need validations, callbacks, or **extra attributes** on the join model."

- [A Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)